# How to create localised urls in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am trying to create localized urls in asp.net mvc.

Let me explain more. i.e.

ControllerName : Recipt
MethodName : Index

I want to change the name of the controller based on the language. i.e.

> "en-gb : uk.test.com/recipt"
>   "fr-BE : be.test.com/fr/rezipt"
>   "nl-BE : be.test.com/nl/reziptdutch"

Note: I set the route table with `"{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`, but it doesn't work as expected. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use the globalization concept provided by the MVC. You don`t have to create these url. It is handled by the MVC. For more details visit [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778040/Beginners-Tutorial-on-Globalization-and-Localizati) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334820/Using-Globalization-and-Localization-in-ASP-NET)